# What are some good ways to test our back-end application?

Tags: mobile, server

We are just a few weeks to launch our mobile application for a few costumers to validate and test.

This application is directly bounded to our server, which runs a back-end RESTful application.

What are some good ways to validate if our server application is protected against attacks and security leaks?

Comment: Contracting a security test provider to test the mobile application, back end software, and server infrastructure is the easy way. However, this question is a bit too broad to answer more helpfully at the moment - there are lots of details on security testing online, including on this site.

Comment: I would restrict it to the mobile frameworks and RESTful API's.

Comment: You'd be at risk of missing issues in the other areas then - it's not uncommon for there to be misconfigurations in server software, or in other applications running on the same system. For example, I've seen SQL injection in an old web app cause problems for a mobile app whose API was on the same server - the client only found this out after investigating poor reviews on app stores mentioning strange behaviours, despite having a mobile app test carried out before release, which didn't find any major issues.

Comment: Please don't use odd-formatting like that. It just makes it harder to read. Also, this is such an open-ended question, it doesn't really have an answer as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing an Android application one simple way to check for common vulnerabilities is running [QARK](https://github.com/linkedin/qark) on it. QARK will scan your app and checks for common security issues.

Similarly, you can use the [ZED attack proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) against the server.

If these tools don't find anything or you fixed all the issues they reported, this does not mean your application is safe. If you want a safe application you should hire a security company to test your application, review your code and provide you with advice.